# Ambiguous assignment in erlang using date & time

Tags: erlang

I'm following Programming Erlang: Software for a Concurrent World written by Joe Armstrong and I am trying to figure out what is asking me solve as an assignment at the end of the sequential chapter. Here is the assignment:

> Look up the definitions of `erlang:now/0` `erlang:date/0` and `erlang:time/0`. Write a function called `my_time_func(F)`, which evaluates the fun F and times how long it takes.

I don't understand what the assignment is asking me to do. Can you give me examples of the output given different arguments or maybe another explanation?

Answer (score 4):

It wants you to write a function that times how long it takes to run another function.

```
my_time_fun:my_time_fun(fun() -> io:format("hi!~n") end).
hi!
This function took 0 megaseconds, 0 seconds, and 54 microseconds to complete
ok
```

Comment: Also you can see description for built-in function timer:tc/1